# Another JNI, C++, DLL, UnsatisfiedLinkError <Native Method>

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've been looking for 2 days now and no solution could help me, so here we go again:

How to fix the UnsatisfiedLinkError... in JNI?

So here's my java code:

```
package org.lingenio.util;

import java.util.*;

public class PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT {

    private native String translateWithPTAPI(String sentence);

    private native void test();

    public PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT(String sentence) throws Exception{
        System.out.println(sentence);
        test();     
    }

    static {
        System.load("C:/Users/michael/Desktop/OmegaT/OmegaT2.3_src/native/PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.dll");
    }
}
```

And here's my C++ Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <jni.h>
    #include "PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.h"

    using namespace std;

    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT_translateWithPTAPI(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring sentence)
    {
/* stuff */
    }

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT_test(JNIEnv *, jobject)
    {
        cout << "This comes from PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.cpp test();" << endl;
    }


    int main(){
        return 0;
    }
```

And the header file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT */

#ifndef _Included_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT
#define _Included_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT
 * Method:    translateWithPTAPI
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT_translateWithPTAPI
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);

/*
 * Class:     PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT
 * Method:    test
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT_test
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and how I build it:

```
call g++ -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -c -DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL -I G:/Software/Java/jdk1.7.0_01/include -I G:/Software/Java/jdk1.7.0_01/include/win32 PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.cpp
call g++ -shared -Wl,-kill-at -o PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.dll -I G:/Software/Java/jdk1.7.0_01/include -I G:/Software/Java/jdk1.7.0_01/include/win32 PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.cpp
```

and finally, the error:

```
10211: Error: Uncatched exception in thread [Thread-14] 
10211: Error: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lingenio.util.PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.test()V 
10211: Error:   at org.lingenio.util.PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.test(Native Method) 
10211: Error:   at org.lingenio.util.PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.<init>(PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT.java:13) 
10211: Error:   at org.omegat.core.machinetranslators.LingenioTranslate.translate(LingenioTranslate.java:32) 
10211: Error:   at org.omegat.core.machinetranslators.BaseTranslate.getTranslation(BaseTranslate.java:64) 
10211: Error:   at org.omegat.gui.exttrans.MachineTranslateTextArea$FindThread.search(MachineTranslateTextArea.java:122) 
10211: Error:   at org.omegat.gui.exttrans.MachineTranslateTextArea$FindThread.search(MachineTranslateTextArea.java:102) 
10211: Error:   at org.omegat.gui.common.EntryInfoSearchThread.run(EntryInfoSearchThread.java:85)
```

I don't know exactly about these two lines of g++ here, I think the second one would be sufficient, but some tutorial must have offered the other line as well and I kept it.

I'm on Windows 7, using MingW and the latest Java (1.7xxx I believe).

Any help is appreciated, I suspect the error lies in the compilation, but I just don't know how to go on from here.

**EDIT**:

Looking into the dll with DependencyWalker I can see the functions are named like I named them in the .cpp file. Of course I am calling them from the Java Wrapper with their respective names, i.e. test(). Could that be a problem? Can someone who used JNI often in the past tell me whether this is the correct way?

Comment: this may seem odd, but try removing .dll the file name where you load the library. The project I am currently working on doesnt accept .dll at the end of the file name

Comment: This just leads to the UnsatisfiedLinkError changing from (Native Method) to (Unknown Source). System.load() actually is the right way to load a dll that's not on the standard System.loadLibrary() path.

Comment: Try moving the dll into the source directory and using `loadLibrary()`

Comment: Didn't help. I put the dll in C:\Users\michael\mypath and ran the jar with -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\michael\mypath. The problem is not that the dll is not found. It loads the dll, but then refuses to find the functions in it.

Comment: Since you seem to have found the solution, post it as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out all the code is fine. Actually I *did* make mistakes compiling the header files. You can see if you look at the header files' function names, i.e.:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT_translateWithPTAPI
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);
```

Now, take a look at your Java files' package membership, in my case:

```
package org.lingenio.util;
```

Because I did compile the header file the wrong way, JNI was later not able to find the symbols it was looking for, because it was actually looking for this:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_lingenio_util_PTAPIWrapperForOmegaT_translateWithPTAPI(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring sentence)
```

So, good luck to the people out there dangling with the same problems. I'm obviously not the greatest Java programmer, that's why I had to worry about this for so long. I should have compiled my header files in the correct way in the first place.
Check your package and classpath!

Comment: I'm having this same problem... basically, my function is named to match package X, but I'm trying to call the method from package Y. Could you explain what the "correct" way to compile the headers is?

Comment: I think I just messed up with the function names. As you can see, the package is called org.lingenio.util, and thus the compiled headers should carry that information as well - you can see that in the answer's third code panel: "Java_org_lingenio_util_yadda". I made the mistake to look for 'yadda' instead of "Java_org_lingenio_util_yadda".