# Calling dynamic library method - IntelliJ IDEA project - Java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-native-interface, dynamic-library

I have the following Java native function

```
private static native void fillEnergyArrays(double currentTemp, double concNA, double concMG);
```

The function is implemented in C. The code has been tested and I have created a working dynamic library, libhyfiModel.jnilib, which I can use to call the method from a Java file, Temp.java. There are no problems in this case when I run the program with the one file. The method call works and returns the expected value.

The problem:

I am taking Temp.java and libhyfiModel.jnilib and trying to import them into a large IntelliJ IDEA project which uses Maven as a build manager. I have put my libhyfiModel.jnilib file in my correct directory so it loaded when the program executes. I double checked that it's loaded using this code in Temp.java:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("hyfiModel");
    }
    catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load\n" + e);
    }
}
```

No exception is thrown here, so libhyfiModel.jnilib is found and loaded correctly, but when the native method is executed I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ca.virology.baseByBase.DiffEditor.fillEnergyArrays(DDD)V
>       at ca.virology.baseByBase.DiffEditor.fillEnergyArrays(Native Method)
>       at ca.virology.baseByBase.DiffEditor.main(DiffEditor.java:266)

I have looked at the documentation here https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html and followed the instructions with no success.

So the dynamic library is being loaded and I have added the directory containing libhyfiModel.jnilib as a dependency but the method can not execute... What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I created a new IntelliJ project with just Temp.java and I am able to call the native function with no errors, so I'm thinking there must be a problem with my project configurations. Any IntelliJ experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It wasn't a configuration error since the library was being loaded properly. The problem was with Temp.java package membership used in the IntelliJ project.

I had a Temp.h file that was generated using the command `javah -jni Temp` that contains the C function definitions for my native functions.

I didn't realize that the native function definitions in Temp.h are different when the Java file Temp.java has a specified  package.

I found my answer at [Another JNI, C++, DLL, UnsatisfiedLinkError <Native Method>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418346/another-jni-c-dll-unsatisfiedlinkerror-native-method)

It is shown that the header files' function names change with package membership.